# Pyinstaller Error when running executable after build = "Pyarrow.vendored.version"

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyarrow

I built an executable file using PyInstaller and ran into a "pyarrow.vendored.version" error while running the executable output. Does anyone have any idea how to get around this issue?  It seems to be something that is installed during the pyinstaller build. Any help would be appreciated!

I tried doing just a pyinstaller --onefile -w "file.py" and I also tried the same file.py using auto-py-to-exe... both ended in the same result.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146). Please also add the contents of `file.py` or a [mre] of it so that we can reproduce your error.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and fixed it by compiling with the "--hidden-import" option given to pyinstaller. Here is an example...

pyinstaller.exe -F -n "Program name" --hidden-import=pyarrow.vendored.version program.py

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to mention that the alternative is to add

```
hiddenimports=[‘pyarrow.vendored.version’]
```

to your program.spec file in `a=Analysis()` before running

```
pyinstaller program.spec —-clean
```